# OpenGL-ES Basic Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

Confusing myself with this OpenGL stuff. What I want to do is move a series of vertexes to a position over a certain amount of time. Reading this [tutorial](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/12/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-9a.html) I understand the keyframe and interpolation principle but the way its implemented in the tutorial is way to complex for me.
All my vertex data is in a GLfloat array

```
GLfloat triangle [6];
triangle[0] = 0; //x coord
triangle[1] = 10; //y coord
```

You get the idea ^^. There is no z coord as I don't need 3D. I can draw it fine and have been for a while but now I want to animate.
Anyone know of any good, simple tutorials for losers like me :)
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should be looking for is tutorials addressing the matrix stacks in OpenGL.   What you want to do to animate your object is *not* to hack your triangle array data values, but to apply transformation matrices to translate/rotate/scale your object in the scene.

Here's one for Android but it's OpenGL ES so should equally apply:

http://blog.jayway.com/2010/01/01/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-–-part-iii-–-transformations/